# Como pegar o valor do retorno da função

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como pegar um determinado valor do retorno da função.

Gostaria de pegar o valor Status.

```
 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já tentou response.Payment.Status?

Comment: Isso parece ser assincrono, logo a ideia do "retorno" cai por terra, pois não tem como retornar um valor se ele só vai ser obtido daqui a 5 segundos ou 1 minuto. Se mostrar o que está realmente a tentar fazer será mais facil de ajudar

Comment: @aa_sp Opa sua dica deu certo, estava tentando somente com Payment.Status, Valeu man.

Comment: blza @Renato deixei como resposta pra facilitar ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou deixar aqui como resposta pra ficar mais claro:

```
 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.Payment.Status);
}
```